# ¿Por qué al iterar sobre un listado de ficheros y ejecutar un comando se queda en standby?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, bucle-for

Me gustaría hacer un bwa (es una función que alinea los reads de un archivo con una secuencia referencia) en loop para todos mis archivos.

Esta es la función para un único archivo:

```
bwa mem /data/Adrian_227/Genomes_NCBI/NC_006262.1/NC_006262.1.fasta /data/fasta/PV001_trim.fa > /data/Adrian_227/Genomes_NCBI/NC_006262.1/NC_006262.1.sam
```

Y obtengo el archivo sam como output. Pero cuando quiero hacer en loop ejecuto la siguiente orden:

```
for infile in /data/fasta/*.fa;
do
    bwa mem $infile /data/Adrian_227/Genomes_NCBI/NC_006262.1/NC_006262.1.fasta > outfile=$infile\; 
done;
```

y se queda en standby la consola sin producir ningún archivo
 ¿Cuál es mi error?

Comment: ¿No estás girando el orden de los ficheros? En el comando de arriba primero van los .fasta y después los .fa. Por otra parte, `outfile=$infile` parece incorrecto, además que estás redirigiendo al mismo fichero cuando en el comando inicial lo haces a `.sam`.